# Mat Card 'See More' button to overlap the card under it

Tags: css, angular

I'm trying to implement a quite basic functionality where I have this some cards put like this:
[image]

And when I click 'See More', I'd like to have this:
[image]

But the most I can do is this:
[image]

I've tried many many things: with/without position:absolute, adding a hidden div when we click on See More but I just can't figure it out. Need some help/ideas.

Here's my Stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-card-sample-wx4dnj

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this:

```
<button (click)="card.visible = !card.visible">
        {{card.visible?"See Less":"See More"}}
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But my main concern here was the mat-card overlaping the card under it when we click on 'See More'. 
Apologies for not being clear.

Comment: As I can see here there are no overlapping cards. And also I have checked your stackblitz code which is working fine.

Comment: The issue is that I want them to overlap each other. 
Just like in my second screenshot.